# Group elements of a list using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to group the elements of this list based on the value of the first item of each, but can't make it work.

I'm trying to get [("A",[("EXP1",5),("EXP2", 9)],("B",[("EXP15",8),("EXP24", 4)]] but I get errors:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy, groupBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
    

myGroupElem :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, [(b,c)])]
myGroupElem = map (\l -> (fst . head $ l, map (b,c)  l)) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
          . sortBy (comparing fst)          

lData = [("A", "EXP1", 5),("A", "EXP2", 9),("B", "EXP15", 8),("C", "EXP16", 7),("B", "EXP24", 4)]

main = do
       print $ myGroupElem lData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fixed code:

```hs
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy, groupBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fst3 (x, _, _) = x

next2 :: (a, b, c) -> (b, c)
next2 (_, b, c) = (b, c)

myGroupElem :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, [(b,c)])]
myGroupElem = map (\l -> (fst3 . head $ l, map next2 l)) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst3)
          . sortBy (comparing fst3)

lData = [("A", "EXP1", 5),("A", "EXP2", 9),("B", "EXP15", 8),("C", "EXP16", 7),("B", "EXP24", 4)]

main = do
       print $ myGroupElem lData
```

Your code had two main issues: the first being your use of `fst`, which is only defined on 2-tuples. So, I made a `fst3` that works on 3-tuples. The other was `map (b,c) l`, which is not a valid lambda. So, I made a `next2` function that gets the last two elements of 3-tuples, and map with that instead. You could also just use a lambda:

```hs
map (\(_, b, c) -> (b, c)) l
```